# Django's html email's inline css not working

Tags: python, django, django-email

I am trying to send a mail through HTML email. Everything is working perfectly, but the inline css of html file is not getting rendered in actual email.
**views.py**

```
        subject = 'Activate Your Account.'
        htmly     = get_template('account_activation_email.html')

        d = { 'user': user, 'domain':current_site.domain, 'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)), 'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user)}
        text_content = ""
        html_content = htmly.render(d)
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, '', [user.email])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        try:
            msg.send()
        except BadHeaderError:
            print("Error while sending email!")
```

Here my html file :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="backgound-color:red;position:relative;width:100%;text-align:center;">Email Verification</div>
    Hi {{ user.username }},
</body>
```

Please help!

Comment: What you wrote seems more about html and not about python since all django does is to render the variables inside, it doesn't change any of the html code. How exactly are you trying to send that as email?

Comment: I update the question with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red background is being skipped because of the spelling: `backgound-color` vs `background-color`.

Also did you try different email clients - HTML email is very much it's own art.